# How do I upload this image along with my username?

Tags: php, mysqli

I've worked out this code to upload properly along with some help and now I can't see the username in the database when I do upload the image. Is there something I need to include like `session_start()` into the upload file? I think I already have my session set whenever I log in.

```
    <?php

       $msg = "";
if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
    $target = "profile/images/".basename($_FILES['image']['name']);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
        $db = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "database");
        $result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '" . $username. "'");
        if ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
            $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
        }
        $username = $row['username'];
        $images = $_FILES['image']['name'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO user (images,username) VALUES ('$images', '$username')";
        mysqli_query($db, $sql);
        $msg = "Image Uploaded Successfully";
        header("Location: images.php?uploadsuccess");
    } else {
        $msg = "There Was A problem uploading image";
    }
}
?>
```

There might be something wrong with my query I believe.

```
 <?php
session_start();

if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) {
    header("Location: index.php");
}

include_once 'dbconnect.php';

//set validation error flag as false
$error = false;

//check if form is submitted
if (isset($_POST['signup'])) {
    $first_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['first_name']);
    $last_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['last_name']);
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['username']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
    $password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
    $cpassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['cpassword']);
    $quote = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['quote']);
    $who = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['who']);

    //name can contain only alpha characters and space
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = '".$username."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>=1){
            $error = true;  
            $username_error ='<div class="error-notice">
                            <div class="oaerror danger">
                            <strong>Uh oh!</strong> - That Username is already taken. Please use a different Username.
                            </div>';


        }else{ 
         }
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '".$email."'";
        $result = mysqli_query($con,$sql);
        if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>=1){
            $error = true;  
            $email_exist ='<div class="error-notice">
                            <div class="oaerror danger">
                            <strong>Uh oh!</strong> - That E-mail already in use. Please use a different E-mail.
                            </div>';


        }else{ 
         }

    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/",$first_name)) {
        $error = true;
        $firstname_error = '<div class="error-notice">
                            <div class="oaerror danger">
                            <strong>Uh oh!</strong> - First Name must contain only alphabets and space.
                            </div>';

    }

    if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/",$last_name)) {
        $error = true;
        $lastname_error = '<div class="error-notice">
                            <div class="oaerror danger">
                            <strong>Uh oh!</strong> - Last Name must contain only alphabets and space.
                            </div>';

    }

    if(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $error = true;
        $email_error = '<div class="error-notice">
                            <div class="oaerror danger">
                            <strong>Uh oh!</strong> - Please Enter Valid E-mail.
                            </div>';
    }
    if(strlen($password) < 6) {
        $error = true;
        $password_error = '<div class="error-notice">
                            <div class="oaerror danger">
                            <strong>Uh oh!</strong> - Password must be minimum of 6 characters.
                            </div>';
    }
    if($password != $cpassword) {
        $error = true;
        $cpassword_error = '<div class="error-notice">
                            <div class="oaerror danger">
                            <strong>Uh oh!</strong> - Make sure your passwords match.
                            </div>';

    }
    if (!$error) {
        if(mysqli_query($con, "INSERT INTO users(first_name,last_name,username,email,password,quote,who) VALUES('" . $first_name . "', '" . $last_name . "', '" . $username . "', '" . $email . "', '" . md5($password) . "', '" . $quote . "', '" . $who . "')")) {
            $successmsg = '<div class="error-notice">
                            <div class="oaerror success">
                            <strong>Wooh!</strong> - Successfully Registered! <a href="login.php">Click here to Login</a>
                            </div>';

        } else {
            $errormsg = '<div class="error-notice">
                            <div class="oaerror info">
                            <strong>Hmm.</strong> - Error in registering...Please try again later.
                            </div>';


        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Where are you setting `$username`? Have you looked in the error logs for errors?

Comment: I have not, how do I look for those errors?

Comment: You open the error logs for your web server in a text editor and look for the error generated when you tried to perform the query.

Comment: I don't see any errors of the query. It uploads successfully, it's just that the username doesn't appear in the table on the database.

Comment: You are defining `$username` *after* you try to use it. You have to define it before you can use it.

Comment: I updated my question. I think there is where I defined username

Comment: Which code is the real code?

Comment: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says ***[your script is at risk for SQL Injection Attacks.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)*** Learn about [prepared](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) statements for [MySQLi](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php). Even [escaping the string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string) is not safe!

Comment: **Never store plain text passwords!** Please use ***PHP's [built-in functions](http://jayblanchard.net/proper_password_hashing_with_PHP.html)*** to handle password security. If you're using a PHP version less than 5.5 you can use the `password_hash()` [compatibility pack](https://github.com/ircmaxell/password_compat).  ***It is not necessary to [escape passwords](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36628418/1011527)*** or use any other cleansing mechanism on them before hashing. Doing so *changes* the password and causes unnecessary additional coding.

Comment: The new code I just inserted is where I register the user. I figure that is where you define the username @JayBlanchard

Comment: Is the first code snippet separate from the second? If so, the first code snippet has no idea about `$username` until it is set in line 11. You try to use it in line 7, but since it isn't set yet, your query fails. It would appear that your logic is non-linear or assumes that once you set a variable it is remembered across scripts which is just not the case.

Comment: Everything works out great, I am able to display the values on the page. Can you give me an example of setting it?

Comment: Because I am unable to follow your logic, I cannot give you an example.

Answer (score 0):

You've not set $username in your code. Your Select Query will not work properly. First of all you've to set $username. Otherwise you can get username from database by any other detail like useremail, userID etc.

Comment: In my code up there that I updated right under the first one, is that what you mean by defining the username?

Comment: No, he meant (as I did) defining `$username` in the first code block, which appears to be a separate script.

Comment: Yes in second code your are defining $username. But second code is totally different from first one. Now where is the select query and table to show data in second code?